# How to set Max Items Per Row in Responsive Grids in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have a responsive grid that returns two containers in a row because that's what I want. the problem is that whenever I view the app on a tablet, the grid looks ugly because it expands. I then set the max item per row to 4 so 4 containers appear if the screen is more expansive but I don't want to do this because 3 items per row will appear on some screens. I basically want to set the items per row to 2 on phones and to 4 on tablets and PC. I put my app to be viewable only in portrait mode so I don't want the code to be adjusted according to landscape mode. I just want the items per row to change from 2 to 4 once the width of the screen is more than let's say 2000 px since tablets' widths are usually 2000+ px. Please how can I code this?
My code below

```
child: ResponsiveGridList(
                    horizontalGridSpacing: 15, // Horizontal space between grid items// Vertical space between grid items
                    verticalGridSpacing: 0,
                    minItemWidth: 10, // The minimum item width (can be smaller, if the layout constraints are smaller)
                    minItemsPerRow: 2, // The minimum items to show in a single row. Takes precedence over minItemWidth
                    maxItemsPerRow: 4,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one trick is to use the width of the device screen and handle this issue with simple short `if`
for example:

```
maxItemsPerRow: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width >= 600? 4: 2,
```

Comment: it worked perfectly. i have a question though? why did you write 600 when I asked for the pixels to be 2000 plus. and why did it work

Comment: search this into google "tablet screen size px"

Comment: And Flutter works with the px size of the screens